# Any django reversion tools which follow ContentTypes GenericForeignKey?

Tags: django, version-control, django-models

I'm trying to use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/) on a project that also uses a GenericForeignKey. I want the reversion to follow the generic link. I can't seem to get it working, and as there seems to be no mention of ContentTypes on the django-reversion documentation, I wonder if it's possible. Any ideas?

EDIT: To anyone following this path, I ended up doing manual management of my revision session and adding the relevant objects to the reversion, no need to get `django-reversion` to automatically follow the object graph.

Comment: How did you achieve to add relevant objects to the reversion? You may answer your own question instead of editing it.

Comment: Sorry Török, that would be nice but I can't remember and I threw away the code (it was a throw-away prototype).

Comment: Remember or find the code again, get 50 reps ;)

Comment: Not likely sorry, it was prototype code. In our case we ended up storing JSON in a database field. I don't know if it fits your requirements well enough, but we decided it was a good idea to store any group of related objects that get versioned in one very 'contained' place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer the direct question, but it answers the problem we were trying to solve.

ContentTypes is fragile because of the `contenttypes` table's `ids`.

In our case we ended up storing the set of related objects which we wanted to version in sync in a JSON structure in a database field. We decided it was a good idea to store any group of related objects that get versioned in one very 'contained' well defined place.

Comment: ok you said "what" to do, now all you have to do is to post "how" you do :)

Comment: You can find Django JSON Field snippets on the web. I'm afraid a client paid me to write the actual code so I can't share it!

Comment: Maybe it's in the best interest of the client that his hacks become part of django-reversion ehehe you can post it even if it's super messy ;)

Comment: We didn't actually use `django-reversion` in the end. As revisions are a core part of the functionality we implemented it ourselves. FWIW my employers do open-source bits and pieces like that, but in this case it was too coupled and not really worth the effort.

Comment: Maybe it's in the best of the client that some of his code is open sourced that means he can have free labor to improve it ;) All the community, which probably has done a lot for your client, is looking forward to a django-reversion alternative with better relation support and simpler design.

Comment: I'm sorry, not on this occasion. Anyway, you can write the code in a few hours.

Comment: Can you at least post a technical description of your implementation ? What functions did you create ? How did you hook them ? What functions did you use ? Maybe you could post the code structure and replace the inner code that matters so much to your client with comments ? The bounty expires in 22H and if i award it for this answer then i'll be lowering the standard on bounties i hope you understand that ... Check out this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436504/django-how-to-display-form-errors-for-each-model-object-in-a-inline-formset