# How do you pass a Validation Error to html?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views, django-errors

I am trying to output an error message in my html. I tried using the advice of other questions but I'm still getting the error at the traceback screen, not on the html. Can someone help?

The is my view:

```
def add_user_institution_accounts(request):
    context_object_name = 'variable_used_in `add_user_accounts.html`'
    form = AddUserAccountsForm
    template_name = 'add_user_accounts.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = AddUserAccountsForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            Institution = Institution.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['name'])
            new_entry = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            if Account.objects.filter(user=new_entry, institution=Institution.type).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('This account already exists'), code='invalid')
            else:
                Account.objects.create(user=new_entry, institution = Institution.type)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error")

    return render(request, 'add_user_accounts.html', 
        {'form': form}, 
        {'form_errors': form_errors}, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My html is:

```
{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}"></script>
{% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add account" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the traceback error:

```
ValidationError at /profile/add_user_accounts/
[u'This account already exists']
```

occurring on this line:

```
raise forms.ValidationError(_('This account already exists'), code='invalid')
```

Comment: Please show me your  traceback screen, models and forms

Comment: @GeoJacob. I have added the error.  I don't think the form is the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the validation error in forms;

```
class AddUserAccountsForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(AddUserAccountsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean_name(self):
        Institution = Institution.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
        new_entry = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        if Account.objects.filter(user=new_entry, institution=Institution.type).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('This account already exists'), code='invalid')
        return self.cleaned_data['name']
```

in views;

```
form = AddUserAccountsForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

Comment: I don't think that's right.  Please look at other error examples.  They are done in view.  You trigger the error when your template calls the view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436504/django-how-to-display-form-errors-for-each-model-object-in-a-inline-formset

Comment: Here they are not doing validation error from views, they are just assigning invalid form errors to a variable and sending to template.
form.is_valid() is method in django forms. The good approach to do form validation is from clean() function.

Comment: OK.  The request.user.id doesn't work in forms.  How do I pull the user id when in forms?

Answer (score 0):

@GeoJacob Thanks. To solve the user id issue, I used the following code:

```
def clean_name(self):
    Institution = Institution_long_tail.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
    current_user = wellfyUser.objects.get(id=self.instance.id)
    if Access_token_pair.objects.filter(user=current_user, institution=Institution.type).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('This account already exists'), code='invalid') 
    return self.cleaned_data['name']
```

with view:

```
form = AddUserAccountsForm(request.POST, instance=current_user)
```